# Python Multiprocessing Erroneously Re-Running Entire File

Tags: python, python-3.x, time, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I'm experimenting with multiprocessing in python (on a windows pc) and wrote a test script to compare speeds of a simple procedure with and without multiprocessing. What I expected this to do was calculate three exponentials twice, once via multiprocessing and once normally, print "result" when each of the three multiprocessed calculations finished, and print the time taken for each of the two versions of the calculation. The intended output was:

```
result
result
result
multiprocessing took 0.2
normal processing took 0.4
```

What I actually get is:

```
multiprocessing took 0.0
multiprocessing took 0.0
normal processing took 0.013965368270874023
multiprocessing took 0.0
multiprocessing took 0.0
normal processing took 0.025931358337402344
multiprocessing took 0.0
multiprocessing took 0.0
normal processing took 0.009973287582397461
multiprocessing took 0.0
normal processing took 0.009966135025024414
multiprocessing took 0.0
normal processing took 0.00798344612121582
normal processing took 0.00798344612121582
normal processing took 0.00798177719116211
normal processing took 0.008982181549072266
result
result
result
multiprocessing took 0.5913138389587402
normal processing took 0.005980491638183594
```

It looks like the code is running repeatedly and in a weird order. Furthermore, if I include an else statement with the `if __name__ == '__main__':` which prints "oops" when `__name__` is not `'__main__'`, I see that the code is also running iterations where `__name__ == '__main__'` is not satisfied, which I didn't think was possible.

This is the code I was using, can anyone point out what is making it misbehave? Thanks in advance.

```
import concurrent.futures
import time

def function(x,y):
    return x**y

StartTime1 = time.time()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        f1 = executor.submit(function, 3,4)
        f2 = executor.submit(function, 5,6)
        f3 = executor.submit(function, 7,8)

        for f in concurrent.futures.as_completed([f1,f2,f3]):
            print("result")

FinishTime1 = time.time()

print(f"multiprocessing took {FinishTime1-StartTime1}")

StartTime2 = time.time()

b1 = function(3,4)
b2 = function(5,6)
b3 = function(7,8)

FinishTime2 = time.time()

print(f"normal processing took {FinishTime2-StartTime2}")
```

Comment: How are you executing/starting the program? I tried your code on Linux and it produced the expected output.

Comment: I'm running it using visual studio code on windows

Comment: Sounds like visual studio code executes multiple instances of your program. Did you check your launch settings?

Comment: I hadn't, but Hussein's answer below has solved the problem. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you import or load this file, all the code outside the if condition will be executed.

The proper way to structure the file is to place everything inside methods and then call these methods from the if condition

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

Answer (score 0):

Hussein's solution has worked. For future askers, the adjusted code below has the correct output (note that all the outputs are now indented within the condition `if __name__ == '__main__':`)

```
import concurrent.futures
import time

def function(x,y):
    return x**y

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        StartTime1 = time.time()
        
        f1 = executor.submit(function, 3,4)
        f2 = executor.submit(function, 5,6)
        f3 = executor.submit(function, 7,8)

        FinishTime1 = time.time()

        for f in concurrent.futures.as_completed([f1,f2,f3]):
            print("result")


    

    print(f"multiprocessing took {FinishTime1-StartTime1}")

    StartTime2 = time.time()

    b1 = function(3,4)
    b2 = function(5,6)
    b3 = function(7,8)

    FinishTime2 = time.time()

    print(f"normal processing took {FinishTime2-StartTime2}")
```